# executing node command from js file

Tags: node.js, command-line, build

I'm neewbe in writing node.js command line scripts. In my project we have a multi-app environment. To setup a dev env we need to launch 2 or more apps, so I'm wondering if it's possible to write a script which will do the following :

1. run a `webpack --watch` for my common project which will generate a bundle files
2. propagate bundles to the other apps.
3. launch webpack-dev-servers for others apps in separate terminals.

Is it possible to do that from a node script? At this moment I only achieved to implement the second step - a file propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn a child process with node easily. So you could start multiple child processes from one file.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('webpack --watch',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
});
```

Check the corresponding docs: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback